# microsoft word 2010 download everytime it is opend

Tags: microsoft-word

I own Microsoft Word 2010, but every time I open it on my computer it "installs" word, but it is already installed on my laptop. How can I get that to stop on my windows ten laptop? I use Word frequently, so it is bothersome waiting three minuets for it to "install" every time i open it.

Answer (score 0):

> To resolve this issue, use one or more of the following methods in the
>   order in which they appear in:
>
> Method 1: If you have an earlier version of Office installed, such as
>   Office 2003 or Office 2007, follow these steps:
>
> To have us perform method 1 for you, go to the "Here's an easy fix"
>   section. If you prefer to perform method 1 yourself, go to the "Let me
>   fix it myself" section.
>
> Here's an easy fix
>
> To fix this problem automatically, click the Download button. In the
>   File Download dialog box, click Run or Open, and then follow the steps
>   in the easy fix wizard. This wizard may be in English only. However,
>   the automatic fix also works for other language versions of Windows.
>   If you’re not on the computer that has the problem, save the easy fix
>   solution to a flash drive or a CD, and then run it on the computer
>   that has the problem.

Here a download link from Microsoft and more info 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2528748/microsoft-office-2010-professional-plus-configures-each-time-you-start

Comment: Where is the link?

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing" class="soup-https-fixed). You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Answer (score 0):

**Installing** or **Configuring**?

Anyhow, something is wrong with your current installation. What I'd recommend is to completely uninstall Word/Office from your PC, and then reinstall it from the original installation files.

1. Download the Office 2010 Scrubber tool (extracted from an MS Fix It) from here https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArtfJd5lMp6hgpEBqBpOs-TCKbCelg (you might be warned against downloading it, but it is a legit file from Microsft themselves.)
2. Run the VBS file As Administrador.
3. When finished running restart the PC.
4. Reinstall Word/Office from the installation files. (If you have a legit product key you should download it from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/office to be sure that the installation files are good.)